# Why i get error when i try to open oracle database in c#?

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm beginner in `oracle` database and `c#`. I want to write the simple oracle and `c#` application, write this code:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=BEHBEHZAD;User Id=SYSTEM;Password=beh1368421";
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Connect Successfull!!");
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e1.ToString());

            }
```

but when I run that program  get this error:
[image]

How can I solve that? Thanks.

My Path variable value is this:

```
C:\app\BEHZAD-HUSH\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin
```

Comment: Try this: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12577.htm

Answer (score 0):

It is related to Windows Environment or Oracle Home PATH.Solution is [Here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12577.htm).

> 1 - put the Oracle DB Home in front of the other paths in the PATH
>   environment variable.
>
> 2 - Remove ORACLE_HOME From environment Variable and re-boot PC

Comment: mersi shahrooz jan,lotfan javabeto baram benevis ke chetori Oracle DB Home ro joloye path bezaram?

Comment: See this:http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: I update my question please review

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to this issue:

1 - put the Oracle DB Home in front of the other paths in the PATH environment variable.

2 - Remove ORACLE_HOME From environment Variable and re-boot PC

Oracle author Osama Mustafa notes a solution to the ORA-12577 error.

**Method 1 Steps -**

step 1: RUN: SYSDM.CPL to open Windows System Properties.

step 2: Click on Advanced Tab > Environment Variables…

step 3: Click the Path variable under System Variable, then click Edit.Change the order between Oracle Client Home and Oracle DB Hom.

```
From: D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin;D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\bin;

To: D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\bin;D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin;
```

In other words, put the Oracle DB Home in front of the other path.

Check details [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12577.htm)

Comment: How can i add Oracle DB Home front of the path?please write that for me

Comment: when i remove ORACLE_HOME from environment Variable ,Oralce listner crash

Comment: check the provided link - http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12577.htm

Comment: oh men,that's link don't write number 1 solution

Comment: update my question please review

Comment: i dont have this:C:\app\BEHZAD-HUSH\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin path on my hard disk,dont have client_1 folder

Comment: don't you have anything else in your `Path` variable?

Comment: No my friend,my complete path values is:C:\app\BEHZAD-HUSH\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin